# Cannot compile sass: error "cannot load such file -- bootstrap-sass"

Tags: sass, rubygems, compass-sass, django-pipeline

First time using `sass`. I need just to compile the sass using `django-pipeline`, but I cannot do it caused this error. Any idea why?

I installed the requested gem.

```
$ gem install bootstrap-sass
Successfully installed bootstrap-sass-3.3.7
Parsing documentation for bootstrap-sass-3.3.7
Done installing documentation for bootstrap-sass after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Then I run the compile.

```
$ compass compile sass/
DEPRECATION WARNING:
Sass 3.5 will no longer support Ruby 1.9.3.
Please upgrade to Ruby 2.0.0 or greater as soon as possible.

LoadError on line ["55"] of      /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:   cannot load such file -- bootstrap-sass
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the gem version in `ubuntu 14.04 LTS` I solved the problem installing the newest version of ruby from the ppa: https://www.brightbox.com/docs/ruby/ubuntu/